# Can I stop imap_search from setting emails to READ

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a function that connects to an imap email account (currently testing with gmail) to get emails that are UNSEEN. After getting the emails I loop through them and do `imap_fetch_overview()` and `imap_fetchbody()` on each email.

After running this function all the emails that have been searched get set to READ in the inbox.

Is there anyway to stop this happening? Ideally i'd like the email to remain UNSEEN.

Here is my function

```
function build_email_data(){

    $this->connect();

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($this->inbox,'UNSEEN');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        $data = array();

        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($this->inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($this->inbox,$email_number,1);

            $_data['subject'] = $overview[0]->subject;
            $_data['from'] = $overview[0]->from;
            $_data['body'] = $message;
            $_data['owner_id'] = 1;
            $_data['email_number'] = $email_number;
            $_data['folder_id'] = 1;
            $_data['created'] = timestamp_to_mysqldatetime();
            $_data['updated'] = timestamp_to_mysqldatetime();
            $_data['email_date'] = timestamp_to_mysqldatetime(strtotime($overview[0]->date));

            $data[] = $_data;
        }

        $this->disconnect();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out why they were getting set to READ and also how to stop it.

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($this->inbox,$email_number,1);
```

That code sets the message to READ. By adding FT_PEEK as an option it remains UNSEEN

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($this->inbox,$email_number,1, FT_PEEK);
```

or in case of using `imap_body` :

```
$message = imap_body($this->inbox,$email_number,1, FT_PEEK);
```

References: [imap_body](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php) [imap_fetchbody](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php)

Comment: Again, PEEK sets the use of the recent, not the seen flag.  Unless your server is not rfc compliant....

Comment: Not sure about the rfc complience but from php.net - "FT_PEEK - Do not set the \Seen flag if not already set" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you confusing UNSEEN and RECENT?  Fetching messages will clear the RECENT flag, but only changing the flags (adding \Seen) should change the SEEN flag.

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure what the RECENT flag is exactly. But after the script is run all the messages in my inbox that were set to UNSEEN are now listed as being read in my inbox